# Calculate the following expression value (Complex Numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers, regular-expressions

Hi the following is the equation to solve which I am lost as I do not quite understand the method of using complex numbers to solve. Please help!

$    \sqrt[4]{\frac{-18} {1+i\sqrt{3}}} = \frac {\sqrt[4]{18-18i\sqrt{4}}}{4}$

After multiplying the conjugate. But I do not know how to solve the numerator.

Thank You!

Comment: Could someone please kindly show me a step by step solution? SOrry pretty new to this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would conjugate the denominator and then use DeMoivre's Theorem with exponent 1/4.

Comment: Could you kindly show me the equations as I do not understand the methods you mentioned. Thanks!